# Is it possible to watch for events on all descendant nodes in ZooKeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

When using ZooKeeper is it possible to watch for all events on descendant znodes?

for example if I have:

```
     (/)
     /  \
   (/a)  (/b)
   /       \
(/c)       (/d)
```

Is there a way to watch the root for changes to /a, /b, /c and /d ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no ZooKeeper api to do that, you will have to write your own.

If you are using [Curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator), you can use [PathCache](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Path-Cache) which maintains watches on a node, and that node's children.  You can write some code to create more PathCaches as you discover descendants of the root you are watching.

If you are going to roll your own version of this, it is actually quite tricky to get right.  This [blog](http://www.pongasoft.com/blog/yan/entry/zookeeper_loss_of_events_problem) describes some of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. I just post here for reference for some other person like me.

I'm looking for this too. Following the tip of @sbridges, I think I could do like this.

```
PathChildrenCache pathcache = new PathChildrenCache(client, "/some/path", true);

PathChildrenCacheListener listner1 = new PathChildrenCacheListener() {
    Map<String, PathChildrenCache> listener2s = new HashMap<String, PathChildrenCache>();
    @Override
    public void childEvent(CuratorFramework client, PathChildrenCacheEvent event) throws Exception {
        String path = event.getData().getPath();

        if(event.getType() == Type.CHILD_ADDED) {
            PathChildrenCache cache2 = new PathChildrenCache(client, path, true);
            cache2.getListenable().addListener(this);
            cache2.start();
            listener2s.put(path, cache2);
        }
        else if(event.getType() == Type.CHILD_REMOVED) {
            PathChildrenCache cache2 = listener2s.remove(path);
            if(cache2 != null) cache2.close();
        }

        System.out.println("" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "\t" + event);
    }
};
pathcache.getListenable().addListener(listner1);
```

If someone find something wrong, please tell me.

Comment: You can loose the child's events between getting notification (CHILD_ADDED) and registering your watch on the child

Answer (score 1):

Use the [TreeCache](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/tree-cache.html) instead of the PathCache

Comment: This is a new feature? Since which version?

Comment: @SswaterShi It's been around since v2.7 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CURATOR-33)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by using **Persistent, Recursive Watches** if you upgrade your zookeeper version to **3.6.0**.
see [Persistent, Recursive Watches](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1416) and [Zookeeper Watchers](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.7.0/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches)

Also there is [Curator Persistent Recursive Watcher](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/persistent-watcher.html) support too.